# Custom Dropdown-List in Toolbar

Tags: wysiwyg, jodit

I use Jodit WYSIWYG-Editor in my current project and already know how to add a custom button to the toolbar. But I wonder if it is possible to also add a selectbox (dropdown-list).

I want the user to be able to insert custom text modules from this drop-down list (loaded via Ajax from MySQL database).

Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
{
    name: 'borders',
    list: {
        'double': '2mm double',
        'single': '2mm solid',
        'none':'none',
    },
    exec: ( ed, nodeOrFalse, control, origEvent, btn) => {
        var key = control.args[0], value = control.args[1];
        document.querySelector(':root').style.setProperty('--border-style',value);
        document.querySelector('#certcss').value = ':root{ --border-style:'+value+'}';
        enableSaveButton();
    },
    template: function (ed, key, value) {
        return '<div>' + key + '</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Comment: Fair comment. It doesn't do the AJAX thing but it does provide a list of custom texts (see list:) that get inserted into the edited content (exec:)